# MySQL: LEFT JOIN returns combined rows

Tags: mysql, left-join

I've three tables, and I tried to query these three tables to get the result I want(no combined rows) but, in the result rows are combined.

Here is the tables:

```
monitoring table
id  | code
12  | M-12

monitoring_question_log table
id  | monitoring_id | monitoring_question_id | monitoring_question_choice_id  | textual_answer
11       12              1                           1                               (NULL)
12       12              2                           4                               (NULL)
13       12              3                           6                               (NULL)
14       12              4                           10                              (NULL)
15       12              5                           14                              (NULL)
16       12              6                           15                              (NULL)
17       12              7                          (NULL)                            N/A

monitoring_checklist_log table
id  | monitoring_id | monitoring_checklist_id   | answer
23      12              1                           checked
24      12              2                           unchecked
25      12              3                           checked
26      12              4                           checked
```

Here is the query which I used:

```
SELECT
    m.id,
    m.code,
    mql.monitoring_question_choice_id,
    mql.textual_answer,
    mcl.monitoring_checklist_id,
    mcl.answer
FROM monitoring m
    LEFT JOIN monitoring_question_log mql ON mql.monitoring_id = m.id
    LEFT JOIN monitoring_checklist_log mcl ON mcl.monitoring_id = m.id
WHERE m.id = 12
```

The result of above query is:

```
id  code    monitoring_question_choice_id   textual_answer  monitoring_checklist_id answer
12  M-12            1                            (NULL)             1               checked
12  M-12            1                            (NULL)             2               unchecked
12  M-12            1                            (NULL)             3               checked
12  M-12            1                            (NULL)             4               checked
12  M-12            4                            (NULL)             1               checked
12  M-12            4                            (NULL)             2               unchecked
12  M-12            4                            (NULL)             3               checked
12  M-12            4                            (NULL)             4               checked
12  M-12            6                            (NULL)             1               checked
12  M-12            6                            (NULL)             2               unchecked
12  M-12            6                            (NULL)             3               checked
12  M-12            6                            (NULL)             4               checked
12  M-12            10                           (NULL)             1               checked
12  M-12            10                           (NULL)             2               unchecked
12  M-12            10                           (NULL)             3               checked
12  M-12            10                           (NULL)             4               checked
12  M-12            14                           (NULL)             1               checked
12  M-12            14                           (NULL)             2               unchecked
12  M-12            14                           (NULL)             3               checked
12  M-12            14                           (NULL)             4               checked
12  M-12            15                           (NULL)             1               checked
12  M-12            15                           (NULL)             2               unchecked
12  M-12            15                           (NULL)             3               checked
12  M-12            15                           (NULL)             4               checked
12  M-12            (NULL)                       N/A                1               checked
12  M-12            (NULL)                       N/A                2               unchecked
12  M-12            (NULL)                       N/A                3               checked
12  M-12            (NULL)                       N/A                4               checked
```

**UPDATE:**

The expected result:

```
id  code    monitoring_question_choice_id   textual_answer  monitoring_checklist_id answer
12  M-12            1                            (NULL)             1               checked
12  M-12            4                            (NULL)             2               unchecked
12  M-12            6                            (NULL)             3               checked
12  M-12            10                           (NULL)             4               checked
12  M-12            14                           (NULL)                             
12  M-12            15                           (NULL)                             
12  M-12          (NULL)                          N/A
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT * ........ the rest

Comment: What about INNER join? Or distinct as Arslan mentioned.

Comment: @Arslan.H, thanks for your answer but, that I've already tried.

Comment: @tilz0R, INNER JOIN, doesn't return the expected result.

Comment: could you please paste your expected result.

Comment: Try with GROUP BY, if you can write give me the sql with some dummy data i could solve it.I'm just to lazzy to write it by my own.....

Comment: The result is correct. You are basically doing a cross join (of every row in `monitoring_question_log` with every row in `monitoring_checklist_log` that share the same `monitoring_id` value). And there are **no** duplicate rows in the result.

Comment: What are the duplicate rows? I cannot see any duplicates in the output you posted.

Comment: @axiac might be monitoring_question_choice_id or code,not well described tho

Comment: @Arslan.H the question clearly specifies *"duplicate rows"* both in the title and in the first sentence. A row is a row, not just some fields. There are no **duplicate rows** in the posted output.

Comment: @skm what's the filtering rule? Why those rows and not other rows from the output you get?

Comment: (Update:) so the `mcl.monitoring_checklist_id` and the `mql.monitoring_question_id` are related? If that's the case, there's you missing join condition.

Comment: @axiac, I don't know how to apply filter. Would you please help?

Comment: @skm I'm not talking about SQL. I'm asking what are the business rules. Why should the query return the first row from its current output and not the second or the third one instead?

Comment: @axiac the result should not be combined, that's what I want.

Comment: @skm clear as mud. I asked why the first row in your expected outcome has `(1, 1)` for `(monitoring_question_choice_id, monitoring_checklist_id)` and why the rows having `(1, 2)` or `(1, 4)` for the same pair of columns are not desired. Until you clearly state in the question why that row is expected and the other two are not expected you won't get a useful answer. The question as it is now doesn't provide enough information to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help.

I found a work around for this problem; As I don't want combined data, the way I handled this situation is not using `LEFT JOIN`, I separately queried every table and got what I was expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using left join its giving combination of every `monitoring_checklist_id` with `monitoring_question_choice_id` (No duplication)

If you dont want combinations you will have to somehow determine that which `monitoring_question_choice_id` should come with  `monitoring_checklist_id` (which I dont see practically possible)

The other way is you handle it in your programming language by looping around all rows and making combination with no repetition

Comment: why not use `GROUP BY` a distinct value from the right table?